# AngularJS ng-click vs ui-sref transition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to transition a user from the landing page to a user page. It works fine with `ui-sref`. However, if I change it to `ng-click="go('menu.home')"`, it stops working. When I click on the link, it does not do anything. Is there some kind of option/setting that I am missing?

**The state**

```
.state('menu', {
        url: '/menu',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            "header@": {
                templateUrl: '/Navigation/AuthenticateHeader',
                controller: 'AuthenticateHeader'
                //    function ($scope) {
                //    $scope.message = 'Navigation Header.'
                //}
            },
            "content@": {
                templateUrl: '/Landing/Home',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = 'Home page';
                }
            },
            'landingnav@menu': {
                templateUrl: '/Landing/AuthHeader',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = 'Landing Header';
                }
            },
            'landingcontent@menu': {
                templateUrl: '/Landing/Index',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = 'Landing Header';
                }
            }

        }
    })
    .state('menu.home',
    {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'landingnav@menu': {
                templateUrl: '/Landing/AuthHeader',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = 'single message';
                }
            },
            'landingcontent@menu': {
                templateUrl: '/Landing/Index',
                controller: function ($scope, UserOptionsFactory) {
                    var options = UserOptionsFactory.CheckOptions;
                    console.log(options);
                    if (options !== null) {
                        $scope.isAdministrator = options.isAdministrator;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

**The link with ui-sref and ng-click**

```
<li ng-click="go('menu.home')">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-User"></i>
    <span>User</span>
</li>

<li>
    <a ui-sref="menu.home">
        <i class="fa fa-5x fa-User"></i>
        <span>User</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: How does your `go()` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the UI-Route `go` function in the controller, not the HTML.

#### ui-sref

According to [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options), `ui-sref` is a directive. When you bind `ui-sref` with `<a>` tag, it does state transition binding for you and automatically triggers the state that you assign for. In your case, it will transition to `menu.home`. That's why using `ui-sref = menu.home` works for you.

#### $state.go()

`$state.go()` is a function which you have to trigger in controller, service and other JS file, but not HTML. When you want to performance state transition in the controller side, you need to inject `$state` to the controller.

#### HTML

```
<li ng-click="go('menu.home')">
  <i class="fa fa-5x fa-User"></i>
  <span>User</span>
</li>
```

#### Controller.js

```
/*  
 *  Create a function in controller called go with parameter
 *  This function will trigger state transition with assigned parameter
 *  In this case, the transition state is menu.home
 */
$scope.go = function(state) {
  $state.go(state);
}
```